# Basic probability (conditional)

Tags: probability

In automotive repair, experience has shown that a rough-running engine can be attributed to bad ignition wired 35% of the time, bad spark plugs 80% of the time, and both 20% of the time.

(a) Suppose a mechanic begins to diagnose the problem by checking the spark plugs first and find them to be bad. With this information, what is the probability that the wires are also bad?

For this part I used the rule that P(B|A) = P(B ∩ A) / P(A). 0.20/0.80 = 0.25

(b) If the sparks plugs are found to be good, what is the probability that wires are bad?

This is the one that I'm not sure how to start.

Comment: Well,can you compute the probability that the cause is something other than wiring or plugs?

Answer (score 1):

Let $B$ be the event that the wires are bad and $C(A)$ be the event that the spark plugs are *not* bad. Then just use the same formula:
$$P(B|C(A))=\frac{P(B\cap C(A))}{P(C(A))}$$
Now we can evaluate this in parts.

The probability $P(C(A))$ that the spark plugs are *not* bad is
$$P(C(A))=1-P(A)=1-0.8=0.2$$
The probability $P(B\cap C(A))$ that *only* the wires are bad is
$$P(B\cap C(A))=P(B)-P(B\cap A)=0.35-0.2=0.15$$
So the answer is
$$P(B|C(A))=\frac{P(B\cap C(A))}{P(C(A))}=\frac{0.15}{0.2}=0.75$$